# Multinomial naive bayes - sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
X = np.array([[0.25, 0.73], [0.12, 0.42], [0.53, 0.92], [0.11, 0.32]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X, y)
mnb.predict([[0.11, 0.32]])
```

--> it predicts `0`

Shouldn't it predict 1?

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Comment: @Tgsmith61591
will you answer my question on this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184256/joint-log-likelihood-give-me-wrong-values-why-help-me

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. You can't assume that just because a model has seen an observation it will predict the corresponding label correctly. This is especially true in a high bias algorithm [like Naive Bayes](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Naive-Bayes-considered-to-be-a-high-bias-low-variance-classifier-Why-does-it-converge-faster-than-logistic-regression). High bias models tend to oversimplify the relationship between your `X` and `y`, and what you're seeing here is a product of that. On top of that, you only fit 4 samples, which is far too few for a model to learn a robust relationship.

If you're curious how exactly the model is creating these predictions, Multinomial Naive Bayes learns the joint log likelihoods of each class. You can actually compute those likelihoods using your fitted model:

```
>>> jll = mnb._joint_log_likelihood(X)
>>> jll
array([[-0.87974542, -2.02766662],
       [-0.60540174, -1.73662711],
       [-1.24051492, -2.36300468],
       [-0.54761186, -1.66776584]])
```

From there, the `predict` stage takes the `argmax` of the classes, which is where the class label prediction comes from:

```
>>> mnb.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

You can see that as it currently stands, the model will predict `0` for all of the samples you've provided.

Comment: how do i overcome this?

Comment: You're asking for a silver bullet solution for a huge problem in machine learning (the [bias variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff)). If you want an easy start, get more data and don't expect that a model fit on 4 samples will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends**. Here, you are using only **one** sample **that belongs to class 1** during the fitting/training. Also, **you have only 4 features for each sample** and **only 4 samples** so again, **the training will be poor**.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
X = np.array([[0.25, 0.73], [0.12, 0.42], [0.53, 0.92], [0.11, 0.32]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X, y)

mnb.predict([[0.11, 0.32]])
array([0])
mnb.predict([[0.25, 0.73]])
array([0])
```

The model learns the rule and can **successfully predict class 0** but **not class 1**. This is also known as the trade-off between specificity and sensitivity. We also refer to that by saying that the model **can not generalize** the rule.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to say "In theory yes". In most scenarios of ML classification algorithms, there's really no guarantee to say that a sample from the training set will predict the same label in predictions. Especially in MNB which is high bias.

Comment: yes that it true. I said in theory meaning that since there is no CV used then the prediction on the training set should be good(overfitting) and thus, return 1 for the above case. cheers

Comment: yes but if i only have one sample having class 1, cant it be made to predict 1?

Comment: this is going to be almost impossible. If you have only one sample that belongs to a specific class, then it is almost impossible to fit a model and then learn a decision function.  are you sure that you have only one sample that belongs to class 1 ?